# Move section on scroll inside a div with overflow attribute

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am trying to make a specific div to automatically move as the viewer scrolls down. It works fine when scrolling using the main scroll of the browser.

However, i am trying to make it work inside a container div that has an overflow:auto attribute, so once the viewer scrolls down in that container div, the div with the text "This item will be stucked" should also move along it.

Here's what i have done so far: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqav7361)

HTML:

```
<div class="scrollTest">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="my-sticky-element">This item will be stucked</div>
  <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
  
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-sticky-element.stuck {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
.my-sticky-element {
    background-color:grey;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding:5px 20px;
    width:200px;
    margin: auto;
}

.container{/*container for centering element*/
    background: blue;
    margin: 100px auto;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}


body{min-height:1200px;}/*force scroll for demo*/

.scrollTest{
background: red;
margin-top: 350px;
margin-left:50px;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

JS:

```
//store the element
var $cache = $('.my-sticky-element');

//store the initial position of the element
var vTop = $cache.offset().top - parseFloat($cache.css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
  $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    // what the y position of the scroll is
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    // whether that's below the form
    if (y >= vTop) {
      // if so, ad the fixed class
      $cache.addClass('stuck');
    } else {
      // otherwise remove it
      $cache.removeClass('stuck');
    }
  });
```

Here is what i'm trying to achieve without using position: sticky attrib since it's not working in IE

[Trying to achieve this](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqav7361/11/)

Hope i was able to explain it clearly, and i would greatly appreciate any help that i can get.

Note: I also need it to work on IE, so using position: sticky is not an option..

Comment: Are you looking for a sticky footer?

Comment: not really a footer but a sticky div

Comment: Maybe something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/gv9ugaw9/1/  or this?  http://jsfiddle.net/acmcginley/5wcsa/  or this?  http://jsfiddle.net/oskarrough/SFyCj/  or this?  https://jsfiddle.net/livibetter/HV9HM/

Comment: The first jsfiddle uses a sticky position attribute which wont work on ie. the other 2 wont be a solution to the problem too because it does not have a div that has an overflow auto. Technically, i am trying to make position fixed to work inside a div with overflow auto.